# How to hide sharepoint document library

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I know that document libraries in sharepoint have flag Hidden. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.list.hidden.aspx) you can find some documentation about it.

But i want to hide some libraries from libraries list in my application. So i want to set this flag to 'true'. How i can do that on my sharepoint team site? Maybe some permission changes?

Answer (score 1):

Hiding from certain users? then you should go with the permission settings in that document lib.

Comment: I want to hide from all users. But in permission editor i found only how i can give some permission to the user, but not how to forbid it.

Comment: Just remove all the users from the permission editor. It will be only visible to the library owner （creator).

Comment: It can sounds strange, but i need to hide library from creator. I know, that there are some libraries with Hidden=true;

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can do that through UI but you can definitely do that using SharePoint Designer. Just open your web site in SharePoint Designer navigate to "Lists and libraries", select your library and in "General settings" set flag "Hide from browser" and press "Save".

Answer (score 1):

If I understood question correctly, do the following:

```
string url = "https://contoso.com:666/sites/SiteName/WebName";
Guid listGuid = new Guid(...);        
using(SPSite site = new SPSite(url))
{
    using(SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
      web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
      SPList list = web.Lists[listGuid];
      list.Hidden = true;
      list.Update();
      web.AllowUnsafeUpadtes = false;
    }
}
```

Haven't tested the code, but I believe this should work.

Comment: I know this is old, but this is the correct answer.  Thanks!